# How to clean a state in screen change?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to clean my state when I change the screen, but it's not working on the first attempt, it just works after a few , someone knows how to make it ?

my code :

```
const FormScreen = ({route,navigation}) => {
  const [FieldForm,setFieldForm] = useState([]);
  const [TypeForm,setTypeForm] = useState([]);
  const isFocused = navigation.isFocused();
       
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      setFieldForm([]);
      setTypeForm([]);
    })
    try {
     // console.log(isFocused, FieldForm.length, TypeForm.length);
      if (isFocused && FieldForm.length > 0 && TypeForm.length > 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        setFieldForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey).message);
        setTypeForm(JSON.parse(route.params.paramKey).tipo);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('DEU RUIM',error)
    }
    return unsubscribe
  }, [FieldForm, TypeForm]);
          {...}
```

Would it works if I use callback , if so how can I use then (in this case) ?

Comment: What version of react-navigation and react-native are you using?

Comment: @NishantNair "react-native": "0.66.3" and navigation: version 6 (as I checked they're the latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, do you want to clear the state when you go back from `FormScreen` or just clear the state when you move to any other screen from this one?

For back action, your code seems to ok, but you wouldn't be able to check if the state is in fact cleared, since the *component is unmounted* anyway on back!

As for the focus change scenario, in `react-navigation v6`, you might want to use the [`Navigation Events listeners`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/) to get the screen `focus/blur`. Try to change your code as below:

```
const FormScreen = ({route,navigation}) => {
const [FieldForm,setFieldForm] = useState([]);
const [TypeForm,setTypeForm] = useState([]);
const isFocused = useIsFocused();

useEffect(()=>{
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    setFieldForm([]);
    setTypeForm([]);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
})

// This would not be useful anyway
// const backAction = () => {
//   ...
// };  
// useEffect(() => {  
//   BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
//   return () =>
//   BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
// }, [FieldForm, TypeForm]);
```

Comment: I just want to clear the state when you move to any other screen. Thanks for that answer , but when I use this it returns me that I can't use so many setstate in useEffect. message: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect`. I edited my code please see if I missunderstood something @NishantNair

Comment: Because you're used [FieldForm, TypeForm] as your useEffect dependency, and inside you have again changed those state variables by setFieldForm and setTypeForm.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot